# Gremlin Big Pi operation (product of a sequence of terms) followed by id-based summation

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
V1 = name:"some name1"
V2 = name:"some name2"
V3 = name:"some name3"
V4 = name:"some name4"

E1 = weight:0.2, StartVertex:V1, EndVertex:V2
E2 = weight:0.3, StartVertex:V1, EndVertex:V3
E3 = weight:0.4, StartVertex:V1, EndVertex:V4
E4 = weight:0.5, StartVertex:V2, EndVertex:V1
E5 = weight:0.6, StartVertex:V2, EndVertex:V3
...
```

I have a gremlin query that finds some paths between these vertices.

There is two things I would like to do there.

> 1: I would like to be able to find the product of all the weights in a
>   path (path_edge1.weight * path_edge2.weight * ...)
>
> 2: I would like to be able to sum the resulting products for each path
>   based on the end vertex.

Pseudo code for what I want to achieve:

```
g.V().has('name',REGEX,\".+some_query.+\").inE.outV.inE.FindingAPathSomehow.path{path_score = 1 : foreach edge e: path_score = path_score * e.weight}{it.lastV().id}.sumWhereIdIsEqual(it[1])
```

Hopefully this is somewhat understandable.

I would like to be able to do everything in a pure gremlin/groovy script since I am using RexPro.

I have looked far and wide for an answer, but have not been able to find a way to do this yet.

---

**Further explanation if the above is unclear:**

When querying I am looking for vertices with a substring equal to the "some_query". This will give me a set of start vertices.

With these vertices I am looking for a specific path in my graph that will give me several paths that might look like this:

```
V = Vertex
E = Edge

Path1 = V3 - E2 - V1
Path2 = V4 - E5 - V7 - E1 - V1
```

Each of these edges has a weight property. With this I want to get what is called ["Big Pi" or "Capital Pi"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation) which is the product of a sequence. Think summation (Σ) but with multiplication in stead of addition.

The result of `Path1` would be the weight of E2, or `0.3` in the example above. While `Path2` would have the weight of `E5.weight * E1.weight` which in the example above would be `0.6 * 0.2 = 0.12`.

In this case we start at vertices `V3` and `V4`, and both end at `V1`. In this case I would like to sum the weights of `Path1` and `Path2` because both end vertices are `V1`. This would give the total score of `V1` as `0.3 + 0.12 = 0.42`. If there had been a `Path3` with end Vertex `V2` and score `0.34`, then the resulting list would have to elements in it; `{[V1, 0.42], [V2,0.34] }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.v(1).as('s').outE.inV.loop('s'){it.loops<3}{true}.path
==>[v[1], e[7][1-knows->2], v[2]]
==>[v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4]]
==>[v[1], e[9][1-created->3], v[3]]
==>[v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4], e[10][4-created->5], v[5]]
==>[v[1], e[8][1-knows->4], v[4], e[11][4-created->3], v[3]]
```

The above uses the toy graph to get some paths that produces multiple results with the same endpoint.  Since you to multiply the edge weights for each path and then sum them for each vertex ending a path, it would seem that a good return value for all this would be `Map` keyed on the end vertex with a value being the list of lists of weights for each path.  To do that, I used a `groupBy`:

```
gremlin> m=g.v(1).as('s').outE.inV.loop('s'){it.loops<3}{true}.path.groupBy{it[it.size()-1]}{it.findAll{it instanceof Edge}.collect{it.getProperty("weight")}}.cap.next()
==>v[3]=[[0.4], [1.0, 0.4]]
==>v[2]=[[0.5]]
==>v[5]=[[1.0, 1.0]]
==>v[4]=[[1.0]]
```

The first closure to the `groupBy` provides the key (i.e. the last vertex in the path).  The second closure filters the `Edge` objects and pulls off the weight to store in the list of paths for each key.  From here you can operate with the `m` or `Map` to finish the calculation.  At this point we're basically just doing straight Groovy.  The following shows the calculation of the product of the weights:

```
gremlin> m.collect{k,v->[(k):v.collect{p->p.inject{product,weight->product*weight}}]}           
==>{v[3]=[0.4, 0.4000000059604645]}
==>{v[2]=[0.5]}
==>{v[5]=[1.0]}
==>{v[4]=[1.0]}
```

Once you have that much, calculating the sum per end vertex is just done with the groovy `sum` function:

```
gremlin> m.collect{k,v->[(k):v.collect{p->p.inject{product,weight->product*weight}}.sum()]}
==>{v[3]=0.800000011920929}
==>{v[2]=0.5}
==>{v[5]=1.0}
==>{v[4]=1.0}
```

Note that I'm breaking this up into multiple Gremlin statements for ease of explanation and readability, but if you like the single line style you could go that way too.  The best way to get it back to single line would be to add a third closure to the `groupBy` which will act as a reduce step to calculate the weight product/sum.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped me out there! :D there is a lot of stuff happening here. To me this is similar to regex in compactness. Really nice, and hard

Comment: @Cort3z I made a minor adjustment to the code to properly key the final representation of the `Map`.  it was originally displaying as 'k' when it should have been the "last vertex" itself.

Comment: I figured that out myself. I ended up making tuples `[k, v.collect... `, however when I use your method I get a weird result. I get something like this: `==> {"86384"=>{"_value"=>0.6137, "_key"=>{"some_data_property_on_vertex"=>"some data", "_id"=>86384, "_type"=>"vertex"}}}`. This could be due to my rex wrapper. Anyways, I need to sort it, so doing it as tuples `[Vertex, result]` lets me sort easily.